# Cassandra Schema for Reddit Posts,Top posts,new posts

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spring-data-cassandra

I am new to Cassandra and trying to implement Reddit mock with limited functionalities. I am **not** considering subreddits and comments as of now. There is a single home page that displays 'Top' posts and 'New' posts. By clicking any post I can navigate into the post.

1)Is this a correct schema design?
2)If I want to show all-time top posts how can that be achieved?

**Table for Post Details**

```
CREATE TABLE main.post (
    user_id text,
    post_id text,
    timeuuid timeuuid,
    downvoted_user_id list<text>,
    img_ids list<text>,
    islocked boolean,
    isnsfw boolean,
    post_date date,
    score int,
    upvoted_user_id list<text>,
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, post_id), timeuuid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timeuuid DESC)
```

**Table for Top & New Posts**

```
CREATE TABLE main.posts_by_year (
    post_year text,
    timeuuid timeuuid,
    score int,
    img_ids list<text>,
    islocked boolean,
    isnsfw boolean,
    post_date date,
    post_id text,
    user_id text,
    PRIMARY KEY (post_year, timeuuid, score)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timeuuid DESC, score DESC)
```

Comment: Hi,  it is not clear in the question what it is your issue. Could you tell us?

Comment: Hey, Luciana!
I have updated the question. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, Agarwalsukant!  It is more easy to see the error message to answer your question 1. Could you share us the message when you run the two `CREATE` in the cqlsh prompt? For the question 2, you need to think in your mock test's logic. In the Cassandra's DB you need to create one table per home page, because it is a noSql db. Every data you need, it should have in your table.

Comment: Hi @agarwalsukant, I wanted to state a point that when we use the full primary key (partition & clustering columns) to query a Cassandra table, we will fetch only a single record. You could also explore the [data modeling by examples](https://www.datastax.com/learn/data-modeling-by-example) web-based training to practice.